# How to retrieve woocommerce Orders note

Tags: angular, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to retrieve Woocommerce orders notes using the woocommerce API  '/wp-json/wc/v3/orders/id>/notes' but am having this error "woocommerce_rest_shop_order_invalid_id"

This my Code

**myservice.service.ts**

```
  siteUrl:string ='https://example.com';
  apiUrl:string ='';
  woocommercePath:string ='/wp-json/wc/v3/';
  ordersByCustomer:any ;

    getOrderNote(orderId){ 
        this.apiUrl = `${this.siteUrl}${this.woocommercePath}orders/${orderId}/notes?consumer_key=${this.consumerKey}&consumer_secret=${this.consumerSecret}`;
        console.log('API URL for order: ', this.apiUrl);
        this.ordersByCustomer = this.http.get( this.apiUrl); 
        return this.ordersByCustomer;  
    }
```

I don't know where I got it wrong

**My ordernote.ts file**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-notifications',
  templateUrl: './notifications.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./notifications.page.scss'],
})
export class NotificationsPage implements OnInit {

 orderNotes: any;

  constructor(private WC: WoocommerceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let isUserLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem('currentUserId');
    this.WC.getOrderNote(isUserLoggedIn).subscribe((data)=>{
      this.orderNotes = data;
      console.log('All Orders Note by a customer', this.orderNotes);
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: What about the part where orderId is supposed to originate?

Comment: I have included it